# How to extract an Avro file from Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, plsql, avro

I have got an Oracle 19c database on a Unix server where several PL/SQL procedures extract data in CSV every day.
Now I need to add an extraction to Avro file.

GoldenGate or Debezium (as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59226466/2311867)) are not an option because I can't change the current architecture, moreover I have not found any Oracle function that helps on this task.

How to extract data from Oracle to Avro file using only PL/SQL or bash scripts?
Serializing the data with a Java class (as in this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/avro/serialization_by_generating_class.htm)) running on Oracle is a viable option? And what about its performance?

Comment: Oracle's Big Data Appliance (like Exadata but for NoSQL) came with built-in support for Avro files. I don't think they have ported that functionality into the regular DBMS platform.

Comment: Thanks @APC, no I have not found any DBMS function for this.